# Application loses focus hide window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode

Ive been attempting to hide my applications main window when the application loses focus.

Upon testing

```
- (void)applicationDidResignActive:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{

[window orderOut:self];

  _isShown = NO;

}
```

however this only seems to work once, after I bring my window back with

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];

[window orderFrontRegardless];
```

It no longer works, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `_isShown` have significance elsewhere? Are you changing the application delegate somewhere? What exactly “no longer works”? Does the application activate successfully? Does the window simply not hide the second time? Does the `applicationDidResignActive:` method no longer get called?

Comment: _iSShown is a internal property I maintain, Its not called anywhere else b/c it only works once. The window DOES NOT hide the second time, and applicationDidResignActive is never called again.

Comment: `_isShown` is a variable; since its value is not a pointer to a function, it *can't* be called. How are you using its value elsewhere? You also haven't answered two of my other questions: Are you changing the application delegate? Does the application activate successfully?

Comment: Peter, I just mean that the only place that _isShown is, is in my header file. I am not changing the application delegate at all, and yes it activates successfully. I applied applicationDidBecomeActive and sent an NSLog to ensure that this is the case. One thing to note, it works the very first time the window is hidden, but the second time the Method never gets called.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you actually want an `NSPanel`, or at least make your window return YES for `-hidesOnDeactivate`.

Comment: Setting the method hidesOnDeactivate to return YES didnt work :(
I dont want a Panel b/c my whole application is 1 window, and needs to hide when its not the main focus.

Comment: I also tried, [self setHidesOnDeactivate:YES]; in my NSWindow Subclass and that didnt work either.